# Sendgrid API - Creating HTML Email Template via API

Tags: python, django, sendgrid, email

I am not able to figure out how I can create an HTML email template in Sendgrid using the v3 API.

I need to add HTML templates on Sendgrid on the fly on the basis of user input (the user uploads an HTML file the platform which makes an API request to Sendgrid)

I need to be able to send the entire HTML (along with Headers and Styles) to Sendgrid for processing these email.

I am able to send basic HTML tags like paragraphs and headings but not the entire HTML.

Can someone guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a template first & then need to add its version.
Take a reference of [create template](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/transactional-templates/create-a-transactional-template)
and then [create its version](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/transactional-templates-versions/create-a-new-transactional-template-version)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31639948)